# How to prove that ring of polynomials in two variables is not a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I am aware that a few questions like this have been asked before, but I am struggling to even understand what an ideal of such a ring would look like. I've been looking at some of the examples here but basically all of them have gone over my head; the most helpful one I have found is on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal), namely the first example in the section '***Examples of non-principal ideals***'. If I am understanding the notation correctly, then there is a specific ideal of $R[x,y]$, namely $$\langle x,y \rangle = \{ xf + yg : f,g \in R[x, y]\} $$

Now the article mentions a generator $p$ for this ideal, but I don't understand what $p$ would be in this case, because isn't $\langle x,y \rangle$ alread the generator? I can mostly understand the rest of the proof, but I'm struggling to see what $p$ might look like, and why $x, y$ must be divisible by $p$. Is $p$ more accurately a polynomial that would be generated by $\langle x,y \rangle$? Or is this totally incorrect?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If $p$ is a generator, then $\langle x, y\rangle = \langle p\rangle$. Therefore in particular $x, y\in\langle p\rangle$, so that $x = pf$ and $y = pg$ for some $f, g\in R[x,y]$. Does that help?

Comment: Ok, I see why this implies that both $x, y$ must be divisible by $p$. But why do we have the first equality at all?

Comment: @koolmathsgames: The first equality is just the definition of what it means for $p$ to be a generator of $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: @EricWofsey ok that makes sense. but why must p then be a non zero constant if it divides x,y?

Comment: @koolmathsgames Because $x\ne0\ne y$ by definition.

Comment: Right ok that should've been obvious to me, but thank you for clarifying